# Query entity and return back a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm trying to query a view (entity) from the database and return back a dictionary.  There are duplicates in the view so I tried groupby and I can't figure it out.

```
var queryresults = db.MyView.Where(x => x.year == myYear)
                            .GroupBy(g => new { g.myCode, g.myCodeName})
                            .ToDictionary(d => d.myCode, d => d.myCodeName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should group by dictionary key property if you want to avoid duplicate keys error. Then you can select code name of first item in each group as dictionary entry value:

```
var queryresults = 
      db.MyView.Where(x => x.year == myYear)
        .GroupBy(x => x.myCode)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().myCodeName);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was close.